# Item that looks like the keyboard's Backspace key in the notification panel?

Tags: notification-icons

I would like to know what the icon that looks like a backspace keyboard key in the upper-left hand side of the notification panel means (what application does it correspond to?).

In the screenshot given below the icon is found in the very left-most position in the notification icons area.

[image]

Thanks.

Comment: If you can, please provide some kind of screenshot, so we know what you're talking about. Otherwise, I think the icon you mean is the indicator for 2 or more other notifications.

Comment: OK, I've added the screenshot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the indicator for 2 *or more* other notifications. Their icons have been hidden because they would overlap other (system) icons.

The icon is not bound to an app (well, it's *System UI* but I don't treat it as an app) and is only removable by swiping away enough notifications, so that all the icons fit into your notification bar.

Comment: Would have been nice if you could swipe the notification icons left and right like you can do with the buttons at the top of the notification panel, clock app, etc...